# Cassandra's listen address is always listening on an ipv6 address

Tags: java, cassandra, nosql

My cassandra instance is always listening on an IPV6 address(for native_transport_port) while all other ports are on IPV4 address. My configure is like[image]

and from netstat you can see the port 9042 is on IPV6:[image]

I don't know how this happens. I even set listen_interface_prefer_ipv6 to false but it doesn't work. The cassandra is of version 2.2.3.

"-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" is also set as JVM_OPTS.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is not an issue. It's IPv4-remapped IP, so the IPv6 application serves both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Details can be found at [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzab6/uafinet6.htm)